# Sum of Nested Table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a nested table of items and I'd like to use sql statements like sum on it if possible. Something like...

```
create type SumMe as object
(
  my_num number
);
/
create type SumThese as table of SumMe;
/
declare
  local_summation SumThese;
  l_totalSum number;
begin
  --populate local_summation
  select sum(my_num) into l_totalSum from local_summation;
end;
```

Is this possible? Nested tables aren't required but I do need to store the array type into a database table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [table collection expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#sthref6751) to treat your table type as a table in a query:

```
select sum(my_num) into l_totalSum from table(local_summation);
```

Quick demo:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
  local_summation SumThese;
  l_totalSum number;
begin
  --populate local_summation
  local_summation := SumThese();
  local_summation.extend(2);
  local_summation(1) := SumMe(22);
  local_summation(2) := SumMe(20);

  select sum(my_num) into l_totalSum from table(local_summation);
  dbms_output.put_line('Total: ' || l_totalSum);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Total: 42
```